# How do I copy only top-level files in a Gradle copy task?

Tags: gradle, groovy, copy

I have the following folder structure:

```
myfolder/
├── mysubfolder/
│   ├── x.txt
│   ├── y.txt
│   ├── z.txt
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
├── d.txt
```

I'd like to copy only the top-level files (no subfolders) into a backup folder under the same folder, like so:

```
myfolder/
├── mysubfolder/
│   ├── x.txt
│   ├── y.txt
│   ├── z.txt
├── backup/
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.txt
│   ├── c.txt
│   ├── d.txt
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
├── d.txt
```

How can I achieve this with a copy task? I'm trying the following:

```
copy {
    from "myfolder"
    into "myfolder/backup"
    include "*"
    exclude "**"
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
copy {
    from "myfolder"
    into "myfolder/backup"
    exclude {it.file.isDirectory()}
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty succinct to me. With groovy you can access "getters" as properties. So you can do `exclude {it.file.directory}`